# How do I create a macro that will run multiple already created macros

Tags: google-apps-script, function-call

So if I have the following macros:

Pmoney
Psteel
Ptitanium
Pplant
Ppower
Pheat

and I would like to create a new function/Macro that will run all of the above at once.

I understand there is a Call function on Excel but can't seem to make this work on Apps script

I tried:

```
function Callmacros(){
 
 Call Pmoney
 Call Psteel
 Call Ptitanium
 Call Pplant
 Call Ppower
 Call Pheat

}
```

It did not work as I don't think "Call" is a function in Apps Script

Comment: There is a javascript call method of Function but it is not used like you propose here. Take a look at it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have some problems with this if you are changing the contents of a spreadsheet in one and then reading the values of the same spreadsheet in another.  In reality I would avoid this and just put everything in one function because it will run faster and I can probably reduce the number of lines significantly through chaining or looping.

```
function macros(){
  Pmoney();
  Psteel();
  Ptitanium();
  Pplant();
  Ppower();
  Pheat();
}
```

- [Learn more about writing javascript functions here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)